# How loud is an iPhone 6 in dB (unweighted)?

Tags: iphone, speakers

How loud is an iPhone 6 is if you make an unweighted measurement in dB?
I found this, but they use a pop filter on the microphone. How loud is it really?

[image: Image of iPhones being tested for dB]

Comment: Those devices are most certainly calibrated for use with the windsock. Because sound is logarithmic, the noise would need to increase about 10 fold for it to double, meaning the difference in a few bels is negligibly tiny.

Comment: Ok. But here it said that wind noise can be attenuated by 20 db and more: https://books.google.de/books?id=eh60Ue_K2QkC&pg=PA578&lpg=PA578&dq=pop+filter+db&source=bl&ots=4xkMiSC-LM&sig=729MLFmYt4f3akVeE0SM05YQrOc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGkKirvaHZAhWL2SwKHY7jCrQ4ChDoATAAegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=pop%20filter%20db&f=false

Comment: Just curious why you want to know this info?  Do you find your iPhone 6 too loud?

Comment: No. I don't, but I put it directly on my ear, and then the alarm started by accident (it was on full volume).

Comment: And by the way, these measurements were made in dbA and I need dB SPL.

Comment: How loud would it be without the pop filter?

Comment: I measured it with a decibelmeter but it shows me 109 dB with and 122 dB without the popfilter. Why is there such a big difference?